# Standard Positional to Bijective Base Conversion

Tags: math, numbers, radix

We know that a `b-based` [standard positional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) number system uses digits, 
`0, 1, 2, ..., b-1`. But a [bijective number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) uses digits, `1, 2, ..., b`. So a `4-based` standard number system sequence looks like,

```
0
1
2
3
10
11
12
13
20
21
22
23
30
31
32
33 (base-4, 16th number standard)
100 (base-4, 17th number standard)
101
.
.
.
```

On the other hand bijective number system for `4-based` looks like,

```
λ (base-4, 1st number, empty-string)
1
2
3
4
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
31
32
33 (base-4, 16th number bijective)
34 (base-4, 17th number bijective)
41 
.
.
.
```

Example:

34152 (in bijective base-5) = `3×54 + 4×53 + 1×52 + 5×51 + 2×1 = 2427` (in decimal).
119A (in bijective base-10, with "A" representing the digit value ten) = `1×103 + 1×102 + 9×101 + 10×1 = 1200` (in decimal).

I wonder if there is any easy way to find `n'th` position bijective value in same base.

For example,

lets say in `base-4` **5th** positional value = **10 (standard)** but **5th** positional value = **11 (bijective)**. Any pseudocode is ok to understand the concept.

Comment: With your reputation and being a member for so long, you should know better than this. You should know [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How is zero represented in your 'bijective' system?  Also, how does the bijective system represent the numbers corresponding to `33` and `100` and `133` and `333` in the positional system?

Comment: There is no zero when it is bijective number system @JonathanLeffler

Comment: It's interesting that such a number system still effectively has leading zeros.  E.g., what is the answer to `3/5` in base 5, bijective? The consequence seems to be that the nth position bijective value is only 1 larger than the corresponding standard value.  Can one not simply compute in the standard rep, then convert by adding 1?

Comment: How do you want to store the numbers in your C program? As strings?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b not actually, it depends on base and number of digits too. So incrementing by 1 wont help I guess.

Comment: @4386427, whatever the data structure, I just want to print the nth bijective value for position n in decimal.

Comment: @DavidBowling I don't follow, 100 is base-4 bijective, and corresponds to 41 in what representation?

Comment: @DavidBowling, I see.  33 above was a poor example.

Comment: I still think you only need to add 1 to the standard representation, then scanning LSd -> MSd, borrow wherever you encounter a zero.

Comment: hmm...the rule for adjacent zeros is tricky, when working through a large base-2 example, though.

Comment: Your example wasn't in decimal; it was in base-4. I was interested in how the positional notation numbers like 33 (base 4) and 100 (base 4) appear in the bijective system. It would also be helpful to have the numbers aligned in the system. Presumably, 1 means the same thing in both base-4 systems; ditto for 2 and 3. The problems start when the positional notation goes to 10 and the bijective goes to 4. And I'd still like to see the examples at the switch between 2-digit and 3-digit numbers in the two systems. OTOH, I'm not so interested that I'll worry about any updates you do (or don't) make.

Comment: And I see that the transition from 2-digit to 3-digit numbers is causing grief in the comments to one of the answers.

Comment: Dear All, I apologize for misleading question, please see my corrected post. Actually I forgot the empty string for bijective number sequence. in base-4, 33 std = 33 bijective, 100 std = 34 bijective. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#Properties_of_bijective_base-k_numerals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This routine implements the conversion. (Which resolved to @4386427's method.)  If you want the other version, where 100 (base 4 std) -> 41 (base 4 bij') then compile with `-D NO_EMPTY_STRING`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void print_be_digits(const char *prefix, const unsigned char *le_num, size_t len)
{
  size_t i;
  printf("%s", prefix);
  for(i=0; i<len; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", (int)le_num[len-i-1]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void nth_bij(int n, int k)
{
  ssize_t i;
  size_t std_len;
  size_t bij_len;
  size_t work;
  unsigned char le_std_digits[256];
  unsigned char le_bij_digits[256];

  //convert to standard radix-k digits
  work = n;
  for(std_len = 0; work; std_len++)
  {
    le_std_digits[std_len] = work % k;
    work /= k;
  }

  print_be_digits("  std: ", le_std_digits, std_len);

  //convert standard to bij
  memcpy(le_bij_digits, le_std_digits, std_len);
  bij_len = std_len;

  #ifdef NO_EMPTY_STRING
  // Step 1: increment LSd
  le_bij_digits[0]++;
  #endif

  // Step 2: borrow on zeros
  // scan back from the end
  for(i=bij_len-1; i>= 0; i--)
  {
    //if we find a zero, borrow, and ripple toward MSd as necessary
    if(le_bij_digits[i] == 0)
    {
      size_t j;

      //Ripple borrow toward MSd, as necessary
      for(j=i+1; j<bij_len; j++)
      {
        le_bij_digits[j-1] = k; //k is the radix

        if(--le_bij_digits[j])
        {
          break;
        }
      }//end ripple

      //adjust bij_len if we rippled to the end
      if(j == bij_len)
      {
        bij_len--;
      }
    }
  }//end scan
  print_be_digits("  bij: ", le_bij_digits, bij_len);
}
```

Simple driver:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Test: 16 decimal (->base 4): \n");
  nth_bij(16,4);
  printf("\n");

  printf("Test: 8 decimal (->base 2): \n");
  nth_bij(8,2);
  printf("\n");

  printf("Test: 13 decimal (->base 2): \n");
  nth_bij(13,2);
  printf("\n");

  printf("Test: 2427 decimal (->base 5): \n");
  nth_bij(2427, 5);
  printf("\n");

  printf("Test: 1200 decimal (->base 10): \n");
  nth_bij(1200, 10);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Compiling for my version:

```
$ gcc -D NO_EMPTY_STRING bij.c
$ ./a.exe
Test: 16 decimal (->base 4):
  std: 1 0 0
  bij: 4 1

Test: 8 decimal (->base 2):
  std: 1 0 0 0
  bij: 1 2 1

Test: 13 decimal (->base 2):
  std: 1 1 0 1
  bij: 2 2 2

Test: 2427 decimal (->base 5):
  std: 3 4 2 0 2
  bij: 3 4 1 5 3

Test: 1200 decimal (->base 10):
  std: 1 2 0 0
  bij: 1 1 10 1
```

Compiling for @4386427's version:

```
$ gcc bij.c
$ ./a.exe
Test: 16 decimal (->base 4):
  std: 1 0 0
  bij: 3 4

Test: 8 decimal (->base 2):
  std: 1 0 0 0
  bij: 1 1 2

Test: 13 decimal (->base 2):
  std: 1 1 0 1
  bij: 2 2 1

Test: 2427 decimal (->base 5):
  std: 3 4 2 0 2
  bij: 3 4 1 5 2

Test: 1200 decimal (->base 10):
  std: 1 2 0 0
  bij: 1 1 9 10
```

Comment: That's just an intermediate step in the conversion.  I'll paste code here in a second.

Comment: Dear All, I apologize for misleading question, please see my corrected post. Actually I forgot the empty string for bijective number sequence. in base-4, 33 std = 33 bijective, 100 std = 34 bijective. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#Properties_of_bijective_base-k_numerals

Comment: Yeah, I had to change the way I handled sequences of adjacent 0s.  It's close to the first post, but subtly different.  Agree that it was quite the ride.  I haven't had that much fun programming in a while.

Answer (score 3):

If a number in the standard base-n system contains **no** zeros, the number has the same representation as bijective base-n.

So you need to look for zeros in the standard number. When you find a zero, replace it with the maximum symbol in the bijective and decrement the element to the left.

Simple example:

```
10 decimal ->  A bijective because 0 becomes A and 1 decrements to zero
20 decimal -> 1A bijective because 0 becomes A and 2 decrements to 1
```

As a special case you must handle sequences of zero.

Simple example:

```
200 decimal ->  19A bijective (i.e. step 1: 1A0 step 2: 19A)
```

You can also look at it like this

```
200 decimal is constructed as 2*100 + 0*10 + 0*1 = 200 decimal
```

For bijective you can't have zero so you'll do:

```
19A bijective is constructed as 1*100 + 9*10 + 10*1 = 200 decimal
```

To finish a bit more complex example:

```
110 decimal ->  AA bijective (i.e. step 1: 10A step 2: AA)
```

Comment: He forgot the `+1`.  Otherwise 100 -> 101 -> 41.

Comment: In base-4 `100` will go to `34` bijective (i.e. 100 base4 is 16 decimal (1*16+0*4+0*1) and bijective 34 (3*4 + 4 = 16 decimal))

Comment: @DavidBowling - Can we agree that `34` in base-4 bijective is 16 decimal? As it is 3*4 + 4*1 = 16 decimal  ? And that `100` in standard base-4 is 16 decimal as well ?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - see comment above

Comment: @4386427 I think that depends on whether 1 in the bijective system maps to 0 in the standard system.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - 1 is 1 in both. The difference is that one representation uses {0, 1, 2, ..., base-1} and the other uses {1, 2, ..., base}

Comment: But the OP said 100->41 when I objected earlier.

Comment: @DavidBowling - It's because OP doesn't count the `empty string` as a position in the bijective. So OP looks at the bijective as {1, 2, 3, 4, 11, ...} while OP looks as standard base-4 as {0, 1, 2, 3, 10, ...} So maybe I misunderstood OP question. My suggestion maps between identical values - not between positions... Hmmm...

Comment: @DavidBowling I agree that the question can be considered unclear. Still, the empty string is a representation for zero per definition. Therefor it shall be counted as well.

Comment: Dear All, I apologize for misleading question, please see my corrected post. Actually I forgot the empty string for bijective number sequence. in base-4, 33 std = 33 bijective, 100 std = 34 bijective. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#Properties_of_bijective_base-k_numerals

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan - In that case my answer should be what you are looking :-)